# How would you like your coffee?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

> How would you like your coffee?

‘How do you like your coffee?’ can have a couple of meanings as said in [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39975/does-this-have-two-meanings-how-do-you-like-your-coffee). When a modal verb *would* is used instead of *do*, can the sentence be meaning variously?

Comment: *How would you like to **have** your coffee?* -InE with the answer *Yeah, with milk and sugar please.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this exact wording *would* invokes the future - the waiter is asking what you want in your coffee (milk,cream,sugar, etc).

It could also be used for emphasis after say you've been discussing the various merits of having coffee in various ways, and you'd put stress on the word.

How *would* you like you coffee?

But it still has the same meaning.